# Best way to .replace() all instances of a String in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, data-structures

In python I receive the following datastructure from a database:

```
{
  "field":"Somestring/somestring.jpg?<<TOKEN>>",
  "list": [
     {"field": "sometring.html?<<TOKEN>>"},
     {"field2": "otherstring.mp4?<<TOKEN>>"}
   ]
}
```

And this structure might very well be expanded to include more lists with fields.

I wish to replace all instances of "<<TOKEN>>" that appear in different strings throughout my data structure, with a validation token used in other to acces the urls that these strings represent.

Is there a better way to do this, than accesing each field with a loop, checking if its a string, and thereafter running: `field.replace("<<TOKEN>>", my_token)`

Comment: could you just load the whole `json` as string, and do the `replace()` on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Recursive approach

This works like a walker, go inside at each level of the data structure and apply the cure handling the correct type.
This let you to handle special cases too or particular data types.

```
var = {
  "field":"Somestring/somestring.jpg?<<TOKEN>>",
  "list": [
     {"field": "sometring.html?<<TOKEN>>"},
     {"field2": "otherstring.mp4?<<TOKEN>>"}
   ]
}

def replacer(obj, val:str):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj.replace('<<TOKEN>>', val)
    
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [replacer(x,val) for x in obj]
    
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k:replacer(x,val) for k,x in obj.items()}
    
    # other cases
    #if ...
    return obj

    
    
replacer(var, 'ciao')

#{'field': 'Somestring/somestring.jpg?ciao',
# 'list': [{'field': 'sometring.html?ciao'},
#  {'field2': 'otherstring.mp4?ciao'}]}
```

#### Using a serializer

as told by @Mahrkeenerh (kudos)
This is a trick, the json-fied version is a string too, so result more performing to do a single replace.

**serialize -> cure -> deserialize**

```
import json
json.loads(json.dumps(var).replace('<<TOKEN>>', 'ciao'))

#{'field': 'Somestring/somestring.jpg?ciao',
# 'list': [{'field': 'sometring.html?ciao'},
#  {'field2': 'otherstring.mp4?ciao'}]}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I decided to go with the recursive approach as the datastructure will be expanded to include different objects etc. and this elegant solutions can account for all that.